# PHP - how to find temperature trend

Tags: php, algorithm, temperature

I have an array of last readings from **temperature sensor**.
How to find id the trend is going high or low.

I know I can compare last value, but this in not a good idea, because temperature tend to flow.

So let's say we have last readings in array:

```
$temp_array = array(5.1, 5.5, 6, 5.9, 6.2, 6.1);
```

How to find answer for question: **is temperature will grow, or will go down based on last readings?**

I am thinking to count average from last 3 vs first 3.
The average from first 3 is 5.533, and the average from latest three is: 6.066 - so I will say that trend is high. But maybe it is a smarter idea to do that?

Comment: What is expected trend for your `$temp_array`? Up or down?

Comment: @kerbholz but that's the question - find out what's more likely

Comment: Do you have any existing code?

Answer (score 2):

Calculating a trend depends on many factors and the context it is calculated in.

For example, your rate of measurement will dictate your solution. For example, if you measure outside temperatures every hour, then looking at the last 3 measurements might make sense.

On the other hand, measuring every minute means you will get caught up in changing trends when even a cloud goes in front of the sun and you most likely don't want that (unless you try to predict solar-cell efficiency).

As you can see, the answer and algorithm to use can depend on a lot of factors.

Have a look in Excel of LibreOffice Calc and investigate the trend lines there. You'll see many types and complexity.

Your proposal might work fine for your use-case, but might be problematic as well. Did you consider a missing or wrong measurement? Example: 8.1, 8.0, 0, 7.9, 7.8, 7.7 ? In this case you will predict the wrong trend.

Keeping things simple, I would do something like:
- Filter out large deviations (you know the domain you are in, high changes are unlikely)
- Count the average
- Count how many measurements are below and above the average

Note, this is just a quick alternative, but it would make the prediction less biased to recent measurement.

Good luck.